# Should I have a singleton ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to be shared different services?

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have declared ThreadPoolTaskExecutor as a @Bean as per my application context as :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
@EnableCaching
public class ApplicationConfig {
    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 2;

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(POOL_SIZE);

        return pool;
    }
}
```

I have 2 different services that need get wired an instance of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. Each service will submit a Runnable that will do some service-specific job.

For example, these are the 2 services:

```
@Service
public class TerminatedContractsService {
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExec;

    public void notifyTerminatedContracts(Date d) {
        // do some contract specific work
        taskExec.submit(() -> System.out.println("emailing terminated contracts...")); 
    }
}


@Service
public class SalaryCalculationService {
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExec;

    public void calculateSalary(Date d) {
        // do some salary related work
        taskExec.submit(() -> System.out.println("calculating salaries...")); 
    }
}
```

Is should be safe to share the same ThreadPoolTaskExecutor instance (since its singleton) for both services right?

Do you foresee any issues with this and if I should prototype instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's ok for multiple services to use the same executor. There isn't any state kept by the executor that would make it a good idea to throw it away and create a new one.

There can be things to look out for. If you have tasks of varying duration that you submit to the same executor, short duration tasks can be blocked if they are queued up behind long running ones. You may want to make sure tasks submitted to an executor have similar durations.

Also if you have some category of task that you need to execute predictably and reliably you might want to reserve a dedicated executor for it. Otherwise if those tasks share a queue with others and there's an issue that prevents those tasks from completing or just slows them down, then the tasks you need executed reliably may be stuck queued up behind them.

But no, prototype scope shouldn't be necessary.